# Javascript needs to reference table starting at certain row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of script that is pulling data from a google spreadsheet that is automatically populated from google analytics. My problem is when the data is automatically fed into the spreadsheet it adds 14 rows of data before the data I want to reference and I am not able to change that. I am hoping to get the script to start pulling data from `<tr>` 15 instead of the first `<tr>`.

Here is my current script

```
/// <reference path="../jquery-2.0.3.js" />
/// <reference path="../jquery-2.0.3.intellisense.js" />
/// <reference path="../gChartsIntellisense.js" />
/// <reference path="smartResize.js" />

a; (function ($) {

var me = $(document);

//Initialize Charts
google.load('visualization', '1.1', { packages: ['controls'] });

$.fn.chartsPlugin = function (options) {
    //Merge passed options with defaults
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.chartsPlugin.defaults, options);

    //Call functions of the plugin
    return this.each(function () {
        me.trigger('drawCharts', opts); /*Pass in the plugin options object*/
    });
};


me.on('drawCharts', function (event, opts) {
    console.log(opts);

    var chartContainers = $('div[data-gChart]');
    console.log('Chart container count: ' + chartContainers.length);

    $.each(chartContainers, function (i) {

        /*Grab the html container declared as chart*/
        var o_ds = $(chartContainers[i]);

        /*Add desired chart size*/
        o_ds.addClass(o_ds.data('chartsize'));

        var ds = o_ds.data('datasource');
        var chartType = o_ds.data('gcharttype');
        var containerName = o_ds.data('containername');
        var chartTitle = o_ds.data('charttitle');
        var horizontalChartTitle = o_ds.data('horizontalcharttitle');
        var verticalChartTitle = o_ds.data('verticalcharttitle');



        console.log('Container ' + i + ' data source = ' + ds);

        //Run the query for this chart
        var query = new google.visualization.Query(ds);

        //Select data in query statement
        query.setQuery('SELECT A,B,C,D,E');

        //Send query with callback function.
        query.send(handleQueryResponse);

        function handleQueryResponse(response) {
            if (response.isError()) {
                //alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
                //return;

                query.setQuery('SELECT A,B,C,D,E');

            }
            console.log('Handling query response.');


            //Grab the data as a data table
            var data = response.getDataTable();

            /*What type of chart are we drawing?*/
            switch (chartType) {
                case 'bar':
                    //console.log(chartType);
                    drawBarChart(containerName,
                                 chartTitle,
                                 horizontalChartTitle,
                                 verticalChartTitle, data, opts);
                    break;
                case 'column':
                    //console.log(chartType);
                    drawColumnChart(containerName,
                                 chartTitle,
                                 horizontalChartTitle,
                                 verticalChartTitle, data, opts);
                    break;
                case 'pie':
                    //console.log(chartType);
                    drawPieChart(containerName,
                                 chartTitle,
                                 horizontalChartTitle,
                                 verticalChartTitle, data, opts);
                    break;
                case 'bubble':
                    //console.log(chartType);
                    drawBubbleChart(containerName,
                                 chartTitle,
                                 horizontalChartTitle,
                                 verticalChartTitle, data, opts);
                    break;
                case 'candlestick':
                    //console.log(chartType);
                    drawCandlestickChart(containerName,
                                 chartTitle,
                                 horizontalChartTitle,
                                 verticalChartTitle, data, opts);
                    break;
                case 'line':
                    //console.log(chartType);
                    drawLineChart(containerName,
                                 chartTitle,
                                 horizontalChartTitle,
                                 verticalChartTitle, data, opts);
                    break;
                default:

            }
        };


    });
});

/*Bar Chart*/
function drawBarChart(containerName, title, vTitle, hTitle, data, opts) {
    console.log('Ready to draw chart');
    console.log(opts.chartsFont);

    var barchart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'BarChart',
        'containerId': containerName,
        'dataTable': data,
        'options': {
            'hAxis': { title: hTitle },
            'fontName': opts.chartsFont,
            'vAxis': { title: vTitle },
            'title': title,
            'legend': 'bottom',
            'animation': { 'duration': 1000, 'easing': 'out' },
            'colors': opts.colors

        }
    })

    /*Draw the chart*/
    barchart.draw();

    /*Add responsiveness*/
    $(window).smartresize(function () {
        barchart.draw();
    });

};

/*Column Chart*/
function drawColumnChart(containerName, title, vTitle, hTitle, data, opts) {
    console.log('Ready to draw chart');
    console.log(opts.chartsFont);

    var columnchart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
        'containerId': containerName,
        'dataTable': data,
        'options': {
            'hAxis': { title: hTitle },
            'fontName': opts.chartsFont,
            'vAxis': { title: vTitle },
            'title': title,
            'legend': 'bottom',
            'animation': { 'duration': 1000, 'easing': 'out' },
            'colors': opts.colors

        }
    })

    /*Draw the chart*/
    columnchart.draw();

    /*Add responsiveness*/
    $(window).smartresize(function () {
        columnchart.draw();
    });

};

/*Pie Chart*/
function drawPieChart(containerName, title, vTitle, hTitle, data, opts) {
    console.log('Ready to draw chart');
    //console.log(opts.chartsFont);

    var piechart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'PieChart',
        'containerId': containerName,
        'dataTable': data,
        'options': {
            'curveType': 'function',
            'hAxis': { title: hTitle },
            'fontName': opts.chartsFont,
            'vAxis': { title: vTitle },
            'title': title,
            'legend': 'bottom',
            'animation': { 'duration': 1000, 'easing': 'out' },
            'colors': opts.colors

        }
    })

    /*Draw the chart*/
    piechart.draw();

    /*Add responsiveness*/
    $(window).smartresize(function () {
        piechart.draw();
    });

};

/*Bubble Chart*/
function drawBubbleChart(containerName, title, vTitle, hTitle, data, opts) {
    console.log('Ready to draw chart');
    //console.log(opts.chartsFont);

    var bubblechart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'BubbleChart',
        'containerId': containerName,
        'dataTable': data,
        'options': {
            'curveType': 'function',
            'hAxis': { title: hTitle },
            'fontName': opts.chartsFont,
            'vAxis': { title: vTitle },
            'title': title,
            'legend': 'bottom',
            'animation': { 'duration': 1000, 'easing': 'out' },
            'colors': opts.colors

        }
    })

    /*Draw the chart*/
    bubblechart.draw();

    /*Add responsiveness*/
    $(window).smartresize(function () {
        bubblechart.draw();
    });

};

/*Candlestick Chart*/
function drawCandlestickChart(containerName, title, vTitle, hTitle, data, opts) {
    console.log('Ready to draw chart');
    console.log(opts.chartsFont);

    var candlestickchart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'CandlestickChart',
        'containerId': containerName,
        'dataTable': data,
        'options': {
            'hAxis': { title: hTitle },
            'fontName': opts.chartsFont,
            'vAxis': { title: vTitle },
            'title': title,
            'legend': 'bottom',
            'animation': { 'duration': 1000, 'easing': 'out' },
            'colors': opts.colors

        }
    })

    /*Draw the chart*/
    candlestickchart.draw();

    /*Add responsiveness*/
    $(window).smartresize(function () {
        candlestickchart.draw();
    });

};

/*Line Chart*/
function drawLineChart(containerName, title, vTitle, hTitle, data, opts) {
    //console.log('Ready to draw chart');
    //console.log(opts.chartsFont);

    var linechart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'LineChart',
        'containerId': containerName,
        'dataTable': data,
        'options': {
            'hAxis': { title: hTitle },
            'fontName': opts.chartsFont,
            'vAxis': { title: vTitle },
            'title': title,
            'legend': 'bottom',
            'animation': { 'duration': 1000, 'easing': 'out' },
            'colors': opts.colors

        }
    })

    /*Draw the chart*/
    linechart.draw();

    /*Add responsiveness*/
    $(window).smartresize(function () {
        linechart.draw();
    });

};

/*Line Chart*/
function drawGeoChart(containerName, title, vTitle, hTitle, data, opts) {
    //console.log('Ready to draw chart');
    //console.log(opts.chartsFont);

    var geochart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'GeoChart',
        'containerId': containerName,
        'dataTable': data,
        'options': {
            'hAxis': { title: hTitle },
            'fontName': opts.chartsFont,
            'vAxis': { title: vTitle },
            'title': title,
            'legend': 'bottom',
            'animation': { 'duration': 1000, 'easing': 'out' },
            'colors': opts.colors

        }
    })

    /*Draw the chart*/
    geochart.draw();

    /*Add responsiveness*/
    $(window).smartresize(function () {
        geochart.draw();
    });

};

//Plugin options
$.fn.chartsPlugin.defaults = {
    chartsFont: 'Arial',
    colors: ['#ECECEC', '#BFBFBF', '#737373', '#595959', '#262626']
};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: what does `data` contain after reading the response?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? If so please add the tag to your question.

Comment: I just added all of the code and new tag

Comment: You could use proper JQuery selectors that would omit first 15 rows, something like:
`table tr:gt(15)`
https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/